# Make acronyms from words [R]

Tags: r

I'm trying to turn multiples words into acronyms like in the example below:
For example for text1 we could have "pil cwf lso ...".

But basically I have two problems: I didn't know that multiple gsub in sapply doesn't work, only the first one (here the gsub with "lso")

I tried something with a vector called "a" but gsub doesn't like vectors...

thanks

```
text1 <- "  iforce credit workflow loan studio Demande sur une validation     finale  CWF  Demande sur une validation finale"
text2 <- "  LSO  Pb lors loan-studio du pricing Opportunity ID  O1079224 \nPb somme repayment different du facility amount "
text3 <- "  CWF Abandon d une loanstudio autorisation avec un ceiling CWF Abandon d une autorisation avec un ceiling authosheet\nRequest ID  2015_10_003639"

df <- data.frame(x = c(text1, text2, text3)) 

df<- sapply(df,
  function (data) {
a <- c("loan studio", "loan-studio", "loanstudio")
    gsub(a, "lso", x = data)  
  gsub("credit workflow", "cwf", x = data)  

    gsub("pilotage", "pil", x = data)                                    
    gsub("iforce", "pil", x = data)                                    
    gsub("i-force", "pil", x = data)   
    gsub("force", "pil", x = data)                                    
    gsub("iforce", "pil", x = data) 

      }
)

df
```

---

Update: So the new code is: I've tried to store the result by adding data <- str_replace_all(a, "lso", data) for example but it doesn't work out.

```
text1 <- "  iforce credit workflow loan studio Demande sur une validation    finale  credit workflow  Demande sur une validation finale"
text2 <- "  LSO  Pb lors loan-studio du pricing Opportunity ID  O1079224 \nPb somme repayment different du facility amount "
text3 <- "  CWF Abandon d une loanstudio autorisation avec un ceiling CWF Abandon d une autorisation avec un ceiling authosheet\nRequest ID  2015_10_003639"

library(stringr) # permet d'utiliser str_replace_all

df <- data.frame(x = c(text1, text2, text3)) 

df2 <- df

 df<- sapply(df,
     function (data) {
    a <- c("loan studio", "loan-studio", "loanstudio")
     str_replace_all(a, "lso", data)  

    str_replace_all("credit workflow", "cwf", data)  

    b <- c("pilotage", "iforce", "i-force", "force", "iforce")
    str_replace_all(b, "pil", data)                                             
      }
)

df2
df
```

Comment: `stringr::str_replace_all` can take a named vector, which lets you do multiple replacements simultaneously. Also, you're currently not storing your `gsub` results, so they're not going to accumulate.

Comment: Thanks, but how to do multiple str_replace_all in a sapply ?

Comment: You don't need the `sapply`, because you can replace everything in one call: `replacements <- c('loan.?studio' = 'lso', 'credit workflow' = 'cwf', 'pilotage' = 'pil', 'i?-?force' = 'pil') ; str_replace_all(df$x, replacements)`